# WAS to SQL server connection without MSDTC

Tags: sql, websphere, msdtc

I have a WAS environment setup with DataSources connecting to SQL server environment. We have MSDTC enabled in the SQL environment and it drops a few connections always. Is there any ways I can set that connection up without using MSDTC?

Answer (score 0):

MSDTC, which stands for Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator, enables two-phase commit transactions (XADataSource).  If your applications don't actually require two-phase commit (which allows you to enlist multiple resources in a single transaction), then you could switch your data source configuration to one-phase only (ConnectionPoolDataSource) and will no longer require MSDTC.

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-xa-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15) to documentation from the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver.

Comment: Hi njr, So do you mean that I have to check my app code to know whether it is setup with XADataSource? Or is it something we can check from the environment itself?

Comment: If you configured a data source in the application server, (server.xml if WebSphere Liberty, wsadmin or admin console if traditional WebSphere) that data source would be configured to or defaulting to XA in order for this to occur.  Otherwise, if your application accesses the JDBC driver directly, then that would be in application code.  But either way, before making the switch, you need to check all application code that uses the data source to confirm that you are never enlisting multiple resources in a single transaction.  Otherwise, you need the two-phase commit that XADataSource provides.